# Laravel - Undefined property: stdClass::$text

Tags: laravel-5

Why would $text be providing an Undefined Property error?

If I run dd($mentions) prior to the function it definitely exists and contains the text property.

If I run dd($mention->text) before return and in the function I also get what is expected.

However, the function will not return a value for $text and instead errors out.

```
   $text = $mentions->map(function ($mention) {
        return $mention->text;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet that you have 1 object in the $mentions collection that doesn't have the `->text` property ?

Try:

```
   if(!isset($mention->text)){
       dd($mention))
   }
```

to find out which one.

Comment: Really appreciate it! Didn't even consider that, it was driving me insane! Looks like that was in fact the reason why.